# Multiple plugins in one treegrid (fail) - Extjs 4.1

Tags: plugins, tree, grid, extjs4.1

i have a treegrid and 2 plugin like

```
        plugins: [
        {
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1
            })
        },
        {
            ptype: 'treefilter',
            allowParentFolders: true
        }
        ]
```

If i use one of them that will working well but if i using both i will get error like

[image]

How to fix this error thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enclosing your `Ext.create` in braces `{}`.  Remove those and you should be fine:

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    }),
    {
        ptype: 'treefilter',
        allowParentFolders: true
    }
]
```